# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os
os.system("grep MCM_END /storage/users/siditom/fastspace/AutoCaspSubmission/CASP12/T0860/stage2/xml/*.xml | sort -k 16 | grep -v NaN | tail -10 | awk '{print($1"\t"$16)}' | sed s/:\<ProteinInfo//g | sed s/MESHI.SERVER_weightedMedianScore=\"//g | sed s^/storage/users/siditom/fastspace/AutoCaspSubmission/CASP12/T0860/stage2/xml/^^g | sed s/.scwrl/' '/g | awk '{print ( $1"\t"$3 ) }'")
```

Comment: The line continuation character is "\." One of your "\" is parsed as a line continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Does writing your code as follows fix the issue. I believe your "\t" was read as a line continutation plus a `t` which would be an unexpected character.

```
import os
os.system("grep MCM_END /storage/users/siditom/fastspace/AutoCaspSubmission/CASP12/T0860/stage2/xml/*.xml | sort -k 16 | grep -v NaN | tail -10 | awk '{print($1\t$16)}' | sed s/:\<ProteinInfo//g | sed s/MESHI.SERVER_weightedMedianScore=\"//g | sed s^/storage/users/siditom/fastspace/AutoCaspSubmission/CASP12/T0860/stage2/xml/^^g | sed s/.scwrl/' '/g | awk '{print ( $1"\t"$3 ) }'")
```

Comment: thanks, but now 
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
 the error . what i can do?

Comment: You're missing a `'` or apostrophe character to match the other one. Essentially you started a string but didn't end one before the file ended. You need to place another `'` to match the unmatched `'`.

Comment: i think all is OK in code but error still : os.system("grep MCM_END //storage//users//siditom//fastspace//AutoCaspSubmission//CASP12//T0860//stage2//xml//*.xml | sort -k 16 | grep -v NaN | tail -10 | awk '{print($1/t$16)}' | sed s/:\<ProteinInfo//g | sed s/MESHI.SERVER_weightedMedianScore=\"//g | sed s^//storage//users//siditom//fastspace//AutoCaspSubmission//CASP12//T0860//stage2//xml//^^g | sed s/.scwrl/' '/g | awk '{print ( $1/t$3 ) }'")

Comment: That code runs for me just fine. What system are you running on?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 on linux2